# Why does the C# compiler go mad on this nested LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

Try to compile following code and you'll find that compiler takes >3 GB of RAM (all free memory on my machine) and very long time to compile (actually I get IO exception after 10 minutes).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(a =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(b =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(c =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(d =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(e =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(f =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Count(g => true)))))));
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain this curious behavior?

```
CS Version:     Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929
OS Name:        Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
OS Version:     6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
```

[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: Good call! I just pasted the code into visual studio and it consumed all 4Gb that a 32-bit process is allowed to and then crashed (2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1).

Comment: Add this code to a shared code-base (using notepad) and watch your co-workers machines crash.

Comment: Sounds like a good thing to report on Microsoft Connect, and to the Roslyn team if their compiler exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I believe I've heard Eric Lippert say somewhere (though I don't recall where) that nesting lambdas too often with type inference can cause the compiler some nasty headaches. I can't think where I've seen it though so can't cite a reference. Hopefully the man himself may see this and comment...

Comment: Well done, trim it down and you may have a nice answer for this: [Crash your favorite compiler](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/crash-your-favorite-compiler)

Comment: Kills cold compilers too (tested with 3.5) and all the way back to VS2008 :(

Comment: @Chris - the [Lambda Expressions vs Anonymous Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx) series on his blog (especially parts 4 and 5) demonstrate some of the issues.

Comment: I wonder how much type information you need to add for it not to crash (I'm pretty sure it's the overload resolution in combination with the lambdas, to many combinations :) ) Is it enough to specify type (ie (int e) => Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum((int f) => ...)?

Comment: Roslyn doesn't crash, doesn't seem to use as much memory, but it is crunching the CPU. I'm using 0.7.0.0, not the latest version with experimental features (I think).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Indeed. Part 4 covers exactly this situation.

Comment: @Chris - that's the one I did include as a link in my answer :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Nice. I hadn't noticed the update to your answer. :)

Comment: @flindeberg, specifying the type (Func<int, int>) for each method group solves the issue, check this out: http://ideone.com/O76JRo

Comment: Who wouldn't go mad looking at that code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe that it's related to type inference and/or lambda generation (when type inference has to go in the opposite direction to normal), combined with overload resolution. Unfortunately, just supplying the type parameters doesn't help the situation (where it presumably still has to perform the type checking).

The following code, which should logically be the equivalent code from yours, after lambdas have been analyzed, compiles without issue:

```
static void Main()
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(a);
}

private static int a(int a)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(b);
}
private static int b(int b)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(c);
}
private static int c(int c)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(d);
}
private static int d(int d)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(e);
}
private static int e(int e)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Sum(f);
}
private static int f(int f)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Count(g);
}
private static bool g(int g)
{
    return true;
}
```

---

I believe Eric Lippert has posted before that type inference is one of the places in the C# compiler where (certain problems) may force the compiler to try to solve an NP-Complete problem and its only real strategy (as here) is brute force. If I can find the relevant references, I'll add them here.

---

The best reference I can find is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/26/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-four.aspx) where Eric's discussing the fact that it's the overload resolution work that causes the real cost - remember, [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) has 10 overloads that accept a lambda/method.

Comment: So, basically, compiler bruteforces his way through `10^n` combinations (where `n` is the amount of chained methods). Sounds reasonable (as an explanation, that is).

Comment: @DarkWanderer: `that^numberofpossibletypes`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I understand your thinking, seams really reasonable (by the way the code [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/WHwtwR))

Comment: Your analysis here is correct. Each lambda introduces a factor of ten possible overloads, and all combinations must be checked. I considered adding code that bailed out when the number of combinations got large but never ended up implementing it.

Comment: @EricLippert Time for a pull request! :D